# new angular 14 project made by cli missing multiple packages

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular14

I have updated my global angular version to 14.1.0 and just created a new project
inside my project I tried to do this:

```
ng g m views/my-module
```

but the module is not created and this error occurs in terminal:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Collection "@schematics/angular" cannot be resolved.
See "/tmp/ng-6nV3EN/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

and also when I try to do `ng serve` another error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'copy-webpack-plugin'
Require stack:
- /home/muaaz/Projects/task/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs/common.js
- /home/muaaz/Projects/task/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs/index.js
- /home/muaaz/Projects/task/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/builders/dev-server/index.js
- /home/muaaz/Projects/task/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- /home/muaaz/Projects/task/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- /home/muaaz/Projects/task/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/command-builder/architect-base-command-module.js
- /home/muaaz/Projects/task/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/command-builder/architect-command-module.js
- /home/muaaz/Projects/task/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/commands/build/cli.js
- /home/muaaz/Projects/task/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/command-builder/command-runner.js
- /home/muaaz/Projects/task/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
See "/tmp/ng-sSdlks/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I tried to clean the npm cache & delete "node_modules" then install again with `npm install` but that did not work.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `@schematics/angular` is not installed as a dev-dependency by default. Try running `npm install @schematics/angular --save-dev`. This will install the package.

Comment: I actually ended installing many dependencies that was missing in my project and they are part of angular, can you explain why the `ng new` command did not install them in the first  place?,... sorry for the very late response.

Comment: Now that I think about it I guess your globally installed angular version differs from the version specified in you package.json. Try running `npm list -g @angular/cli` to find out your globally installed angular version. To update your global angular installation, you can run `npm update -g @angular/cli`.

Let me know if my assumption was correct. If so, I'll update the answer to help others with similar issues.

Comment: the global version is 14.1.0 and the one in package.json is the same